# is it possible to externally call a <div class = "something"> with java in browsers url box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm testing how secure is an experiment I'm doing with Javascript.

I have this 'popup' (a form, not external popup in a new window) that shows when a user gets a certain number of points. Is it possible if a person can call that pop-up with a javascript command in the url box. And what command would one have to use?

Here's an example;

```
<div class="popup test withForm">

    <div class="content">

        <img class="title" src="images/popup/victory.jpg" style="height: 100px;" align="center" />

        <div class="text">

            <br />

            You won

            <br />
            <br />



            <form action="example_url.com" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="hidden" id="eventDate" value="1423263600" />
                <div class="line">
                    Enter your info
                </div>
                <div class="line">

                    <div class="left">
                        <input type="text" name="user" id="successUser" class="validateText" value="" placeholder="Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <i class="fa fa-times error"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-check ok"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="line">
                    <div class="left">
                        <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="successEmail" class="validateEmail" value="" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <i class="fa fa-times error"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-check ok"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>


        <br />
        <br />

        <div class="buttonLine">
            <div class="button submit">
                <div>
                    Submit
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>ali</div>


        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <br />
        <br />


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably yes, but definitely it's possible via dev tools (just hit F12).

Comment: Script execution from a url isn't possible as long as the query string of the url isn't drawn on the page or evaluated (using `eval`) within the code. Using the console however allows you to run/change the complete code of the page.

Comment: if you want to know if they can run javascript from adding something to the URL, it depends on how secure the rest of your page is. But that said, you can easily just open a console and type the javascript into it and it'll run just fine. If security is your goal, pass the vars you're tracking via an ajax, have the server side file do the validation/counting and if/when it reaches a certain goal, return and load the form into the container popup div instead of loading the div at the page load time. That's like keeping passwords in `<!-- -->`, too easy to find/exploit by reading the source code

Comment: I do not even need a browser to submit a value to your server.

Comment: @Mouser I think this is what OP means: copy-paste `javascript: alert('Hello!')` to the address bar and hit ENTER.

Comment: @Teemu and then my Google engine is going to search `alert('Hello!')`. I think the OP is worried about some kind of XSS attack. However the described way in the question doesn't allow this except when you somehow handle the querystring and still it's not a real XSS attack. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No, it won't, your browser will alert "Hello!". You can execute JS via address bar by adding `javascript:` pseudo protocol in front of a script text. Chrome seems to omit the protocol when pasting, just write the text, and you'll see.

Comment: What exactly would the attacker have execute (in console as many of you reminded of) so he could call <div class="popup test withForm"> in the example above. This is being called when the user gets a certain amount of points (value).